# Kali Linux Live USB space

Tags: linux, kali-linux, liveusb

I want to know, if i will make live kali persistence usb and put it into my laptop will it use hard drive memory? Because my 500 gb space is emtpy and want to make kali live usb to use that free memory.

Answer (score 2):

The Live USB is confined to the USB.  Simple Kali fits within 32 GB and so get a 32 GB USB key for it.

If you want it on the hard drive, then best to install it as a Virtual Machine. I do this and I am in Kali now.

Even a full set of tools fits inside 40 GB.

That is, you do not need additional hard drive space from your laptop.

So decide your own best course of action and go from there.

Comment: I have usb drive 256 GB , will kali linux use this memory when i will download some tools if i will use live persistence usb?

Comment: Yes a complete set of Kali tools still fits inside 40 GB

Comment: So after flashin kali live , i will download some tools such as some softwares with big capacity. All these downloads will use my usb drive?

Comment: Yes .  I have a very complete z Kali VM - 35 GB

Comment: Kali has existing Live Boot images at https://www.kali.org/get-kali/#kali-live. The "Everything" image download size is 11.63GiB.

Comment: I can get answer to my question guys please.. i have 256 gb usb drive i will make it bootable live usb, so all my downloads after plug in usb to computer will use  memory of  usb or not?

Comment: The answer and comments provide all you need so far as I can see.  Kali Live will fit on your USB drive. You do not need additional hard drive space.

Comment: I did amend my answer to make it very complete

Comment: Um... what downloads? Kali is a toolbox for security professionals, not a desktop distro for surfing the inertwebs and downloading movies. I'm getting the hunch that you actually plan to use it as a desktop - a very bad idea. A lot of things which just work in a desktop distro are _intentionally_ "broken" in Kali, because they are either unnecessary for its purpose, or compromise its security. You can't even fix them without breaking Kali itself. See [Should I use Kali Linux?](https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/) in [Kali documentation](https://www.kali.org/docs).